# Why wont my for loop add fractions past 1.0/10,000,000.0?

Tags: java, for-loop, printing, addition, fractions

I need to add a series of fractions. I looked through other `for` loops on adding fractions, but did not come across the problem I am having. The fractions denominator increases by 1.0 each time until it adds up 1.0/1.0 + 1.0/2.0 + .... + 1.0/ 150,000,000.0. My code has worked for me by adding the fractions until I go a little over 10,000,000 in my for loop. Once I go over say 15,000,000 it just doesn't print anything and the program continues to run. What error did I make? Why won't it print the answer when it's above a certain number?

Here is the code:

```
float sum = 0;
float numerator = 1;
float denominator = 1;

for(float i = 1; i <= 10000000; i++)
{
    sum = ((float)numerator/denominator) + sum;
    denominator++;
}
System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);
```

Comment: Try changing the precision to double (use `double` instead of `float`). And change `float` in the for loop to `int`

Comment: I have to use float as it is for class. For the assignment I have to "use appropriate data type to get 32 bit floating point".

Comment: Ok then, but you should be allowed to change `i` to `int`.

Comment: Also `10000000` is a significant amount of iterations, how long did you wait for your program to finish?

Comment: That works by changing it to type int in the for loop thanks. With that tho I am getting the same answer now weather I do 10,000,000 or 150,000,000? Also it only took a few seconds to print the sum.

Comment: Well like I said, `float` precision is limited. Perhaps that's the point of your assignment?

Comment: @Dunno 10000000 isn't that large of a number at all when you consider the number of operations a modern CPU can carry out per second. My machine took 35 milliseconds to carry the loop out. You'd need an iteration count a few orders of magnitude larger to even consider the "wait" factor. Just FYI :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding `1` to a sufficiently large `float` won't have any effect any more.  The problem is the limited precision of a `float` -- 23 bits.  Once you get to about 16 million (about 2<sup>24</sup>), the difference between consecutive float values is greater than 1.  You can see this by printing out the result of [`Math.ulp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp-float-) (unit in last place) value.

```
if (denominator % 1000 == 0)
    System.out.println("Denominator is " + denominator + ", ulp is " + Math.ulp(denominator));
```

At the point where the output stops, the ulp is 1.0.

```
...
Denominator is 1.6775E7, ulp is 1.0
Denominator is 1.6776E7, ulp is 1.0
Denominator is 1.6777E7, ulp is 1.0
```

At 2<sup>24</sup>, the ulp jumps to 2.0, and adding 1.0 follows IEEE's round towards even rule, and the sum is unchanged.

Change the datatypes to `double` for a much larger precision (53 bits).  Just beware that this change would only prolong the problem until you reach 2<sup>53</sup>.  That would also make your program run *much* longer.  And if you really want to go beyond that amount, use `BigDecimal`s.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing more comments here are my thoughts:

Floats have limited precision. It means that if you add very, very small numbers, the outcome might not be what you'd expect. It also works the other way - adding 1 to a very large number won't change it's value.

In your program to avoid this problem you should increment integer values and cast them to float before summation. Like this:

```
public class Sum {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    float sum = 0;
    float numerator = 1;
    int denominator = 1; //changed to int

    for(int i = 1; i <= 10000000; i++)
    {
        sum = (numerator/(float)denominator) + sum; //this casts denominator to float
        denominator++; //this will now increment integer

    }
    System.out.println("The sum is " + sum);




} 
}
```

Further reading: [Floating point on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)